# How to add a specific product variant to the shopping cart

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

The task is to add a product with selection options to the cart. For example, take product with id:2, which has different color and size options. By clicking on the add product button, the product of the selected option should be added to the cart. Product options are predefined. You can see them in the products array below. At the moment, I have created a cart entity in the global store, where I can add a product without selection options and render it on the cart page.

```
"products" : [
  {
    "type": "simple",
    "id": 1,
    "sku": "s1",
    "title": "Product 1",
    "regular_price": {
      "currency": "USD",
      "value": 27.12
    },
    "image": "/images/1.png",
    "brand": 9
  },
  {
    "type": "configurable",
    "id": 2,
    "sku": "c1",
    "title": "Product 2",
    "regular_price": {
      "currency": "USD",
      "value": 54.21
    },
    "image": "/images/conf/default.png",
    "configurable_options": [
      {
        "attribute_id": 93,
        "attribute_code": "color",
        "label": "Color",
        "values": [
          {
            "label": "Red",
            "value_index": 931,
            "value": "#ff0000"
          },
          {
            "label": "Blue",
            "value_index": 932,
            "value": "#0000ff"
          },
          {
            "label": "Black",
            "value_index": 933,
            "value": "#000"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "attribute_code": "size",
        "attribute_id": 144,
        "position": 0,
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Size",
        "values": [
          {
            "label": "M",
            "value_index": 1441,
            "value": 1
          },
          {
            "label": "L",
            "value_index": 1442,
            "value": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "variants": [
      {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "code": "color",
            "value_index": 931
          },
          {
            "code": "size",
            "value_index": 1441
          }
        ],
        "product": {
          "id": 2001,
          "sku": "c1-red-m",
          "image": "/image/conf/red.png"
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "code": "color",
            "value_index": 931
          },
          {
            "code": "size",
            "value_index": 1442
          }
        ],
        "product": {
          "id": 2002,
          "sku": "c1-red-l",
          "image": "/image/conf/red.png"
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "code": "color",
            "value_index": 932
          },
          {
            "code": "size",
            "value_index": 1441
          }
        ],
        "product": {
          "id": 2003,
          "sku": "c1-blue-m",
          "image": "/image/conf/blue.png"
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "code": "color",
            "value_index": 933
          },
          {
            "code": "size",
            "value_index": 1442
          }
        ],
        "product": {
          "id": 2004,
          "sku": "c1-black-l",
          "image": "/image/conf/black.png"
        }
      }
    ],
    "brand": 1
  }]
```

My store:

```
import {createStore} from 'vuex'
import apiRequests from "@/store/actions/apiRequests";
import commonActions from './actions/actions'
import mutations from './mutations/mutations'
import getters from './getters/getters'

const actions = {...commonActions, ...apiRequests}

export default createStore({
    state: {
        products: [],
        brands: [],
        cart: []
    },
    mutations,
    actions,
    getters
})
```

actions:

```
export default {
    ADD_TO_CART({commit}, product) {
        commit('SET_CART', product)
    },
    INCREMENT_CART_ITEM({commit}, index) {
        commit('INCREMENT', index)
    },
    DECREMENT_CART_ITEM({commit}, index) {
        commit('DECREMENT', index)
    },
    DELETE_FROM_CART({commit}, index) {
        commit('REMOVE_ITEM_FROM_CART', index)
    }
}
```

mutations:

```
export default {
    SET_PRODUCTS_TO_STATE: (state, products) => {
        state.products = products
    },
    SET_BRANDS_TO_STATE: (state, brands) => {
        const includesBrands = {}
        for (const brand of brands) {
            for (const product of state.products) {
                if (product.brand === brand.id) {
                    includesBrands[brand.id] = brand
                }
            }
        }
        state.brands = Object.values(includesBrands)
        state.brands.unshift({title: "All brands"})
    },
    SET_CART: (state, product) => {
        if (state.cart.length) {
            let isProductExists = false
            state.cart.map((item) => {
                if (item.id === product.id) {
                    isProductExists = true
                    item.quantity++
                }
            })
            if (!isProductExists) {
                state.cart.push({...product, quantity: 1})
            }
        } else {
            state.cart.push({...product, quantity: 1})
        }
    },
    REMOVE_ITEM_FROM_CART: (state, index) => {
        state.cart.splice(index, 1)
    },
    INCREMENT: (state, index) => {
        state.cart[index].quantity++
    },
    DECREMENT: (state, index) => {
        if (state.cart[index].quantity > 1) {
            state.cart[index].quantity--
        }
    }
}
```

and getters:

```
export default {
    BRANDS(state) {
        return state.brands
    },
    CART(state) {
        return state.cart
    },
    PRODUCTS(state) {
        return state.products = state.products.map((product) => {
            const brand = state.brands.find((b) => b.id === product.brand)
            return {...product, brandName: brand?.title || 'no brand'}
        })
    },

}
```

Now I am faced with the fact that I do not understand how I can add a certain product variant to the cart and draw it on the cart page.

Comment: It sounds like you need to modify the JSON schema of your store's product object by adding an array that can hold all the options/variants that the user has actually selected before adding to cart

Comment: How can I understand what parameters / variants the user has chosen? Where do I need to get the data from and where do I put it?

Comment: You need to design a page with some type of selection inputs, dropdowns, something the user can interact with so they can choose the options.  You already have all the variant data don't you in `products[i].variants`?  You would use that to populate the input options, then tie the input value back to the product somehow like a new array `products[i].userOptions` that gets added with the rest of the product info when adding to cart.